# How to convert ElasticSearch query to ES7

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

We are having a tremendous amount of trouble converting an old ElasticSearch query to a newer version of ElasticSearch. The original query for ES 1.8 is:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "*",
          "default_operator": "AND"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "terms": {
              "organization_id": [
                "fred"
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 50,
  "sort": {
    "updated": "desc"
  },
  "aggs": {
    "status": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 0,
        "field": "status"
      }
    },
    "tags": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 0,
        "field": "tags"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and we are trying to convert it to ES version 7. Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: here is my attempt, but it's not quite right and I don't know what to do with "aggs" - https://gist.github.com/ORESoftware/4fb70d2f0a3b8a0c48e5452efe634f66

Answer (score 1):

The Elasicsearch docs for [Filtered query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/query-dsl-filtered-query.html) in 6.8 (the latest version of the docs I can find that has the page) state that you should move the query and filter to the `must` and `filter` parameters in the `bool` query.

Also, the `terms` aggregation no longer support setting `size` to 0 to get `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. If you really want all the terms, you need to set it to the max value (2147483647) explicitly. However, the documentation for [Size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.8/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-size) recommends using the [Composite](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.8/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) aggregation instead and paginate.

Below is the closest query I could make to the original that will work with Elasticsearch 7.

```json
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "*",
          "default_operator": "AND"
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "organization_id": [
            "fred"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 50,
  "sort": {
    "updated": "desc"
  },
  "aggs": {
    "status": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 2147483647,
        "field": "status"
      }
    },
    "tags": {
      "terms": {
        "size": 2147483647,
        "field": "tags"
      }
    }
  }
}
```